# What does "live to a higher note" mean?

Tags: quotations

Live honestly to a higher note. Life is too short. So, do the best you can and live your life to a higher note.

Comment: *as if it's your last day*, *to the fullest*, *with no regrets*... pick whatever you like.

Comment: The sequence [*live to a higher note*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22live+to+a+higher+note%22) doesn't even occur *once* in the entire Google Books corpus. Apparently your source is Kimora Lee Perkins, who seems to be a native speaker, but my guess is that was just an "off-the-cuff" coinage with approximately the sense as outlined by @krobelusmeetsyndra.

Comment: Note that similar metaphoric usages include *to live on a higher **plane / level*** (be more "spiritual"), and *to live it **up*** (indulge oneself, enjoy the good life). But they make sense, because ***up / higher*** in those contexts definitely implies ***better***. But high[-pitched] [musical] notes aren't obviously better than other frequencies, so I think the metaphoric usage doesn't really work there.

Comment: There is the idiom to **live to a higher standard**